# slicknav not being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, slicknav

I have question about this slicknav script from slicknav.com

I used the slick nav script to get the hamburger effect at a breakpoint 640px.

http://graph-art.matc.edu/harrisd5/vicom126/a2/index.html

Now if worked just flawlessly in these 4pages of my website:

the home page, aboutus, faq2(frequently asked question), and the index page. would you happen to know why the script isn't working on my portofolio page:

http://graph-art.matc.edu/harrisd5/vicom126/a2/portofolio.html

What am I'm doing wrong to cause the script not to function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you meant by it wasn't working but by inspecting your code i noticed 
`.slicknav_menu {
    display:none;
}`

With the above in your css the slicknav will not display. Replacing the `none` with something else like `inline` as i've done below.

`.slicknav_menu {
    display:inline;
}`

Now all is left is to work on the position and the links to the pages you want

Comment: Oh thanks for the prompt reply, 
When I say it's not working I mean it's simply not being displayed.  Even when switched to displayed inline the menu still doesn't show up on my portfolio page, the other pages it does show up.  The reason why it's set to none is so it doesn't appear until I reach my break of 40em or approximately 640px. 

slicknav_menu {
    display:inline;
}  

Do you know what's causing it to not display?

Comment: can you post your java script, css and html for the page. Only the parts that relate to the slick nav on the portfolio page

Answer (score 0):

On your portfolio page you have two versions of jQuery for some reason.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Removing the second one seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help I was clearly confused I didn't know that I more than one version. So If I have more than one that's causes conflict.